# Can jQuery Mobile be used without altering layout or DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I'm interested in using only some of the components of jQuery mobile (specifically, the tap event handlers and datepicker). What's the best way to make use of the library without it "taking over" the layout and behavior my mobile web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modifying DOM is JQM's main feature. You have to cripple it hard.

Get the repo from git, remove all plugins from manifest, get to the code and find the `.page` method/widget and remove all the code (or leave some bits if you need to get something working - I haven't tried that).

Then run `make` and it will create a stripped jquery.mobile.min.js for you